# Available disk space drops, while used space stays almost still

Tags: disk-usage, monitoring, disk

Recently I found out that on one of my servers (Ubuntu 16.04) I get significant drops on free disk space, at nights:

[image]

zooming to the last 1h (from right now):

[image]

one can see this happens abruptly. Just minutes ago when I ran `watch df` I could see that `Available` and `Use%` for the partition mounted at `/` change very fast, but `Used` is only different by 28B. Eg. just when diskspace started to drop:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      52428800 7700776   4374316  64% /
devtmpfs         2097152       0   2097152   0% /dev
tmpfs            2097152       4   2097148   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2097152  209300   1887852  10% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2097152       0   2097152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             2097152       0   2097152   0% /run/shm
```

and a few minutes later:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs      52428800 7700804   2354044  77% /
devtmpfs         2097152       0   2097152   0% /dev
tmpfs            2097152       4   2097148   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2097152  209300   1887852  10% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2097152       0   2097152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             2097152       0   2097152   0% /run/shm
```

Therefore my question is what happens there, that Used disk space stays almost constant but available space not?

I run 2 web apps on the server but they don't allow any uploading and nginx says no one accesses them at night. I actually expect no disk changes on this system, excluding logs. I tried to use `ncdu \ -e some_file` during the day and at night and then `diff` them, but the output is terrible to read and compare, so I cannot really tell where the growing/new files are at.

(regarding security - no one is logged in except for me and I couldn't spot any unusual processes being run, but will dive into logs later)

Comment: maybe related https://serverfault.com/questions/714219/linux-says-my-space-is-full-with-2-4-50gb-used

Comment: oh god, @frostschutz, you're right, I was totally not looking this direction. I've just triple checked and it really is OpenVZ and other VPSs eating space on host. thanks a lot, might I accept your answer?